# Explode() expects a string

Tags: categories, php

I currently am getting this error:

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in D:\...\portfolio.php on line 12
```

Here is my portofolio.php:

```
<?php 
    $current = get_the_category(); 
    $current_id= $current[0] ->cat_ID; 
    $categs_list = get_category_parents($current_id);
    $pieces = explode("/", $categs_list);  //this is line 12.
    $category_name = strtolower($pieces[0]);
    $categs = get_cat_id($category_name);
    ?>
```

Any Ideas? PHP is not my forte.

Comment: Could you clarify what it is that this code is even attempting to do? It's completely weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the top:

1. `$current = get_the_category();`

   This returns an **array of objects**, one object for each category.
2. `$current_id= $current[0] ->cat_ID;`

   This returns an **object**, the first object in the previous array
3. `$categs_list = get_category_parents($current_id);`

   This returns a **string**, but *only if the current category has parents*; otherwise, it returns whatever was passed to it: which was an **object**

   (See where the problem is yet?)
4. `$pieces = explode("/", $categs_list);`

   This expects a **string**, but is returning an error, because it is being provided an **object**.

**So, Conclusion:**

You are calling this code in a Post that is in a category that **doesn't have any parents**. You need to write some fallback code to account for this occurrence.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still getting the hang of it and having someone break the code apart the way you did is infinitely helpful. Thanks! (I'd give an upvote but not enough rep :( !)